# MySQL Where 2 of x

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

How can i get only Lines, where 2 (or more) Where Clause of many are true?

For Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
WHERE CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name,'".$this->key."'),CHAR) LIKE '%".$this->escape($name)."%'" 
  OR CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name2,'".$this->key."'),CHAR) = '".$this->escape($name2)."'" 
  OR CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name3,'".$this->key."'),CHAR) = '".$this->escape($name3)."'" 
  OR CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name4,'".$this->key."'),CHAR) = '".$this->escape($name4)."'" 
.....
```

is there a simply way to get only the results where 2 (or more) match, without creating a huge SQL Statement (each column with each other column - (name AND name2) OR (name AND name3) OR (name AND name4) OR ... )

Comment: Is it going to be exactly 4 LIKE conditions or more?

Comment: different, i generate the SQL during Runtime (LIKE and "="), but Nick solved the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can utilise the fact that it treats boolean expressions as 1 or 0 in a numeric context. Thus to check for 2 or more conditions being true, you can write

```
WHERE (condition 1) + (condition 2) + ... + (condition n) >= 2
```

Note that the parentheses around each condition are required to prevent any operator precedence issues.